# Como faço para testar métodos do HtmlHelper, AjaxHelper e UrlHelper?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Escrevi algumas extensões para os helpers do MVC. O problema é que não sei como fazer para testar estes métodos uma vez que eu não tenho estes objetos em uma unidade de teste.

Como faço para testar os métodos que criei?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter estes helpers você precisa instanciá-los. Uma maneira prática é ter uma classe com propriedades estáticas, assim você pode obter rapidamente um helper no contexto do seu teste.

```c
public static class Helpers
{
    internal static AjaxHelper<dynamic> AjaxHelper
    {
        get
        {
            return new AjaxHelper<dynamic>(
                new ViewContext { HttpContext = new FakeHttpContext() },
                new FakeViewDataContainer()
            );
        }
    }

    internal static HtmlHelper<dynamic> HtmlHelper
    {
        get
        {
            return new HtmlHelper<dynamic>(
                new ViewContext { HttpContext = new FakeHttpContext() },
                new FakeViewDataContainer()
            );
        }
    }

    internal static UrlHelper UrlHelper
    {
        get
        {
            return new FakeUrlHelper(
                new RequestContext(new FakeHttpContext(), new RouteData())
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Note que estou criando os objetos acima com classes "falsas", em inglês chamadas de *mocks*. Por não existir um contexto Http em um teste unitário você precisa criar um falso contexto.

Para implementar estes *mocks* basta herdar das classes base:

HttpContextBase:

```c
internal class FakeHttpContext : HttpContextBase
{
    // exemplo de implementação de Items, note o override
    private Dictionary<object, object> _items = new Dictionary<object, object>();
    public override IDictionary Items { get { return _items; } }

    // caso você precise acessar o Request, você precisa de um mock para ele
    public override HttpRequestBase Request { get { return new FakeHttpRequest(); } }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

HttpRequestBase:

```c
internal class FakeHttpRequest : HttpRequestBase
{
    public override Uri Url { get { return new Uri("http://www.exemplo.com/"); } }

    public override string MapPath(string virtualPath)
    {
        return System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\temp", virtualPath.Replace("~/", "").Replace("/", "\\"));
    }

    public override string ApplicationPath { get { return "/"; } }
}
```

IViewDataContainer:

```c
internal class FakeViewDataContainer : IViewDataContainer
{
    private ViewDataDictionary _viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
    public ViewDataDictionary ViewData {
        get { return _viewData; }
        set { _viewData = value; } 
    }
}
```

Com os *mocks* acima você pode implementar um teste e utilizar coisas como:

```c
Helpers.UrlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.MapPath("~/arquivo.js");
Helpers.UrlHelper.Content("");

Helpers.HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Add("x", 1);

Helpers.AjaxHelper.ActionLink("Link", "Action", "Controller");
```

E caso precise de mais métodos basta fazer *overrides*.